# Install apache2-dev for mod_wsgi

Tags: debian, apache-http-server, python, django

I'm completely new to linux but have developed a Python3 Django application that I've been asked to deploy to an apache web server running on Debian 7.8.

To do that I'm following Django guideline telling me to install mod_wsgi using [this tutorial](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickInstallationGuide).

When I run ./configure this is what I get:

```
$ ./configure --with-python=/usr/local/bin/python3
checking for apxs2... no
checking for apxs... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for prctl... yes
checking Apache version... ./configure: line 2765: apxs: command not found
./configure: line 2765: apxs: command not found
./configure: line 2766: apxs: command not found
./configure: line 2769: /: Is a directory

./configure: line 2964: apxs: command not found
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
```

I tried installing apache2-dev bu running `apt-get install apache2-dev` but it just gives me `E: Unable to locate package apache2-dev`.

Where can I get apxs2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that apache2-dev is a virtual package provided by apache2-threaded-dev. Installing that should get you what you need.

Comment: Thank you. It indeed got me `apxs2` but I could not compile the mod_wsgi source anyway. In the end I installed the package `libapache2-mod-wsgi` recommended by [this troubleshooting tutorial](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/InstallationOnLinux).